# New Navigation Bar label colour in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a navigation bar and I would like to change its colour, but I can't seem to find in the documentation anything about changing the label colour, any ideas on how to do so? My current code:

```
bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue[100]!,
    destinations: const [
      NavigationDestination(
        icon: Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.white,),
        label: 'Home',
      ),
      NavigationDestination(
        icon: Icon(Icons.money, color: Colors.white),
        label: 'Expenses',
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

as far as I can see the label is a string, but how do I change the colour of this string? My first idea was to use Text(), but label only accepts strings.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 6):

You can wrap the `NavigationBar` widget with `NavigationBarTheme` and then you can apply styles as you like. To change label color you can do the following:

```
bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBarTheme(
    data: NavigationBarThemeData(
      labelTextStyle: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<TextStyle>(
        (Set<MaterialState> states) => states.contains(MaterialState.selected)
            ? const TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)
            : const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      ),
    ),
    child: NavigationBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue[100]!,
    destinations: const [
      NavigationDestination(
        icon: Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.white,),
        label: 'Home',
      ),
      NavigationDestination(
        icon: Icon(Icons.money, color: Colors.white),
        label: 'Expenses',
      ),
    ],
  ),)
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to do as the following:

1. create "your_file_name"_theme.dart. (You may change the color of your preference)

```dart
final ThemeData myappTheme = ThemeData(
  navigationBarTheme: NavigationBarThemeData(
    labelTextStyle: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((state) {
      if (state.contains(MaterialState.selected)) {
        return const TextStyle(color: Colors.orange);
      }
      return const TextStyle(color: Colors.green);
    }),
  ),
);
```

2. In your MaterialApp widget, add the following. (In my case, I called it myappTheme)

```dart
MaterialApp(
    theme: myappTheme,
```

3. Restart the app